# Understanding go mod and cause of package is not in GOROOT

Tags: go

I'm trying to play around with the lightning network. I have cloned the [repo](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd), and on disk placed it here (I'm using windows):

C:\Users\hallibut\Documents\GitHub\lnd

I'd like to run any of the tests in itest, lets say testMultiHopPayments. The cli commands I'm using after I cd into the above location is:

```
go test itest -run testMultiHopPayments
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
package itest is not in GOROOT (C:\Program Files\Go\src\itest)
```

I've read through the various posts on this error, but I'm still not quite sure why it happens, and it's likely because I don't fully understand the go module (I'm new to go). This article, was probably the best in helping me understand the structure and env variables:

https://golangbyexample.com/workspace-hello-world-golang/

My understanding from the various readings is that whatever directory the go.mod file is in, indicates the module level directory. Prior to version 1.13 there was a required directory and structure, but now that should not be an issue if you're using at least version 1.13 and modules. I'm using 1.17.1.  This is somewhat of an assumption or inference, but I believe everything lower in the directory structure is part of a package to be installed as part of the module (and is defined by the package keyword). However, I don't understand why a package with source code within a subdirectory would be missing/throw the aforementioned error. I've also tried running:

```
go mod install github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/lntest/itest
```

That doesn't seem to do anything/has not effect on the error. What am I not understanding about packages? Looking at the go.mod file I observe that itest is not specifically defined anywhere… Not sure if that's required. Also, I assume I've got to run some build process prior? I attempted this with:

```
go install -v ./...
```

Comment: cd into the folder and do `go test`. It is that simple if you properly used modules.

Comment: `go test -run /^testMultiHopPayments$/` no need for the module name, and you can use a regular expression to filter out test methods to run

Comment: So I believe that worked - but I'm still uncertain why the above approach throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS Code and Go Modules, you need to "Open folder" and point to the cloned repo, to get around that error

[image]

Comment: What if I'm just running from command line?

Comment: The next thing to try in that case would be to check your environment, can you check your env values for GOPATH, and GO111MODULE, GOPROXY? I beleive their values should be "", "on", "direct" in your case

Comment: With gopath, with modules it's now common to write packages outside of the gopath, so it's in effect deprecated. Which is why it's unset/set to null